# How can one show that the Levi-Civita symbol is a Cartesian tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus

While studying Cartesian tensors from Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by Mary L. Boas, I came across a proof that the Levi-Civita symbol is an isotropic Cartesian tensor. The proof already assumes that it is a Cartesian tensor. How can one show that the Levi-Civita symbol is a Cartesian tensor in the first place?

Comment: There are multiple definitions of “tensor”. Which one are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281162/

Comment: @Ghoster I mean Cartesian tensor under rotation of Coordinate axes.